# how do you beat Alduin in Skyrim: Elder Scrolls V?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

how do you beat Alduin in Skyrim: Elder Scrolls V?

Answer (score 2):

In The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim (known as 'Skyrim' to the wider gaming audience) you need to use the Dragonrend shout to bring Alduin down to the ground, and then hit him a lot with a weapon or magic until his HP reaches zero.